# Why is binding lost when nesting directive in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**The Issue**

Using my directive within another directive causes certain bindings to be lost, specifically in the `ng-repeat` usage.

The directive is used in many areas of my application without issue. It renders a list of inputs which is passed to it's scope from a parent template, like so:

```
<filter-header filters="filters"></filter-header>
```

---

**Working Scenario**

I have used the following scenario throughout the application and not come across an issue to date.

- `$routeProvider` resolves filters list with WebAPI call for a controller
- controller assigns list to its own scope, like so: `$scope.filters = filters`
- template uses filter-header element and passes filters from it's scope to the directive, like so: `<filter-header filters="filters"></filter-header>`
- The filter-header directive then renders the filters using an ng-repeat without issue. `$$hashKey` is present in each item of the filters collection, indicating the binding's existence.

---

**Failing Scenario**

In the following scenario, the binding seems to be lost and the ng-repeat fails to render anything.

- `$routeProvider` resolves filters list with WebAPI call for a controller
- controller assigns list to its own scope, like so: `$scope.filters = filters`
- template uses a new element directive, assigns filters from it's scope to the new directive's via an attribute.
- directive's template uses filter-header element and passes filters from it's scope to the directive, like so: `<filter-header filters="filters"></filter-header>`
- The filter-header directive then **FAILS TO** render the filters using an ng-repeat. `$$hashKey` is **NOT** present in any item of the filters collection.

Annoyingly, I cannot replicate this in Plunker...

---

**Oddity**

The directive has another collection of item's passed to it, `columns="columns"` (can be seen in the code below). Columns binds correctly and is rendered in it's own `ng-repeat`. I cannot see how Columns is different from Filters as both are used almost exactly the same way.

---

**Looking Deeper...**

I have debugged the process all the way. The filters object is getting all the way to the end scope successfully. If I output the contents of filters to the screen within the final directive, using `{{ filters }}` I can see all of the filters as expected. However, in the very next line where my `ng-repeat` begins, no filters are iterated through.

To be certain it is not my list causing issues, I used a list that already works using the working scenario mentioned above and the `ng-repeat` does not render here.

To be certain it is not my directive's code causing issues, I converted it to a controller and routed directly to it (skipping the nested directive) as in the working scenario mentioned above and the `ng-repeat` now works.

Using `$log` to inspect the list, I notice one difference. In the working scenario, all lists contain a `$$hashKey` property for each item in the list. In the failing scenario, the `$$hashKey` is missing on all items in the list. This seems to indicate that the binding is being lost for some reason.

Can someone tell me the error in my ways? The only real difference I can see in my usage is that I pass the object to an middle-man directive before before passing it on the the directive where it is used. Strangely, in the very same directive, another list is used in a very similar way and it renders without issue within it's `ng-repeat`, and it's item's all have the `$$hashKey` property appended.

---

**Code**

There's a lot of code involved, so I'll try and pick out the relevant parts.

*RouteProvider*

```
$routeProvider.when('/Pride/Admin/AuditForms/:id', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Admin/editAuditForm.html',
    controller: 'editAuditFormController',
    resolve: {
        sectionFilters: function (auditFormSectionRepository) {
            return auditFormSectionRepository.getFilters().$promise;
        },
        sectionColumns: function (auditFormSectionRepository) {
            return auditFormSectionRepository.getColumns().$promise;
        }
    }
});
```

*EditAuditForm Controller*

```
prideModule.controller("editAuditFormController", function ($scope, sectionFilters, sectionColumns) {

    $scope.sectionFilters = sectionFilters;
    $scope.sectionColumns = sectionColumns;
});
```

*EditAuditForm Template*

```
<audit-admin-sections audit-form="auditForm" section-filters="sectionFilters" section-columns="sectionColumns" show-deleted="false"></audit-admin-sections>
```

*AuditAdminSections Directive*

```
prideModule.directive('auditAdminSections', function ($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin/auditFormSections.html',
        scope: {
            sectionFilters: '=',
            sectionColumns: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $route, $timeout, $location, filterLogic, auditFormSectionRepository) {
            // do stuff
    }
});
```

*AuditFormSections Template*

```
<filter-header filters="sectionFilters" columns="sectionColumns"></filter-header>
```

*FilterHeader Directive*

```
prideModule.directive('filterHeader', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/common/filterHeader.html',
        scope: {
            filters: '=',
            columns: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, filterItemsRepository) {
            $log.info("$scope.filters");
            $log.info($scope.filters);
            // This will log the filters as expected, however the $$hashKey property is missing from the items
    }
});
```

*FilterHeader template*

```
<!-- at this point, {{ filters }} produces the list of filters -->
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
    <!-- at this point, nothing renders -->
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ filter.friendlyName }}</label>
</form>
```

---

**Update 1**

I pulled the code out of the directive and into a new controller to mimic the Working Scenario mentioned above. The `ng-repeater` now functions as expected and the `$$hashKey` is present again. So something is definitely related to the difference between **route->controller->directive->directive** vs **route->controller->directive**.

Worth mentioning, on top of the code above, there are watches on the filters among other usages.

**Update 2: Offender Uncovered**

I've nailed it. But it makes no sense yet. It seems as though the `form` element is to blame. Changing to a `div` resolves the issue. I'm thinking this may be an angular bug as I'm struggling to see why this could work in one scenario and not the other.

Comment: can you provide more code - relevant pieces of html/js ?

Comment: `$$hashkey` is added by `ng-repeat` to your collection. The fact that you don't see those `hashkey` means that somewhere, between your controller and your `ng-repeat` a binding is broken. No typo? Nor other variable inside a sub/parent-scope called `filters`?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Have in mind that ng-repeat creates it's own scope, maybe that's your issue

Comment: I tried ripping the code out of the directive and into a controller (so that it works like Working Scenario. This way works without issue and the $hashKey is now present.

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich and others, I have provided code. There's quite a bit to run through, but I believe the relevant pieces are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have discovered two fixes so far, but they are more hacks than fixes as I cannot understand the cause of the original problem. I'm still interested if anyone can point out the real issue, but until then this is the best I have:

**Solution 1**

After much researching, debugging, head scratching, rewriting, I by luck came across a solution. I'm not happy with it, as it doesn't make sense (unless someone can elaborate for me).

The problem seems to be with the `form` element and using the `ng-repeat` attribute on it while being nested in angular `directive`s...!!! This has to be a bug, right?

Solution was as simple as changing this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ filter.friendlyName }}</label>
</form>
```

to this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ filter.friendlyName }}</label>
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2**

It seems that the `$scope` variables were also playing a part in the issue. If I rename each directive's `$scope` variable name for this particular variable (ie, filters) so that it is unique for each directive, the `form ng-repeat` works. This makes it seem like there is some sort of conflict within the directives' isolated scopes, however why this is only an issue for `form ng-repeat` baffles me. As such, it still doesn't explain to me what is the root cause of this behavior.